# Transfer data between unrelated activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have three activities suppose `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` and `ActivityC`
 where A has started B and B started C then B is destroyed.
Now I have to transfer some data back to `ActivityA` from `ActivityC`.

How can I achieve this without using SharedPreference or database in android?

Comment: you could always use [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) and [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) as the flags to your intent you wanna go to with the extra data applied using `putExtra()`.

Answer (score 2):

Make one **Constant.class** and declare string

```
public static String your_value = "";
```

now in your Activity C . store your Value like this.

```
Constant.your_value = "123456";
```

and in your Activity A . access like this.

```
 Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Your constant value "+Constant.your_value);
```

Comment: `and in your Activity A . access like this.`. When?

Comment: @greenapps as mentioned by OP **Now I have to transfer some data back to ActivityA**
so whenever he wants to access the data

Comment: How/When would activity A know that data is available?

Comment: @greenapps  he asked how to transfer data between activity  and I demonstrated it . So He will comment if he would face a problem in implement . So please stop commenting on my post . If you have better solution , above write an answer section is all yours

Comment: Well you could tell how OP could use your solution. Im interested too. You omitted a use case. So i asked already twice. Dont see it as comment but as question.

Comment: @greenapps there are multiple way around to know that data is available . for example you can use boolean to check that data is available or not .

Answer (score -1):

use `setResult()` method for sending data back

In `ActivityC` use this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("data", "yourdata")
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        
finish();
```

Now in your `activityA` override method `onActivityResult()`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             //get your data here
             String strEditText = data.getStringExtra("data");
         }     
    }
}
```

Happy coding!!